# callback script with space in bash

Tags: linux, bash, callback, arguments

I wrote a little script that check something, and i want a command to be executed from within the script if the test was successfull. And i don't want to hardcode the command, but give it as argument to it like a callback script.

The command I testing with is `/usr/bin/xmessage -buttons "button a","button b" some text to test`. Running it within a terminal standalone works fine, no quotation marks needed for the last text.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
$1
```

But when running `/path/to/script.bash '/usr/bin/xmessage -buttons "button a","button b" some text to test'` it looks like [this](http://www.abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto-20.02.bmjm6.png), though the echo looks right.

When using `"$1"` instead of `$1` it complains it couldn't find the file. Anyone got ideas how to fix the behavior with the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you write the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${1+"$@"}
${1+"$@"}
```

And call it like this:

```
/path/to/script.bash /usr/bin/xmessage -buttons "button a","button b" some text to test
```

Comment: Can this be used if the command is the second argument of the script?

Comment: Yes. All arguments are stored in `$@` and `${1+"$@"}` is a perfect way to use them in the script.

Comment: I meant something like `script.sh otherarg1 otherarg2 callback`

Comment: In this case, you need `${1+"${@:3}"}`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an array.

See the following link on how to fix your problem: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
eval $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `eval "$1"` or redesign so that the callback is specified after all options - a common arrangement would be something like `script.bash -options arguments etc -- /usr/bin/xmessage -buttons "button a","button b" some text to test`

Comment: How to call the callback in case of the redesign?

Comment: Basically `shift` away the leading arguments, then run `"$@"`, which is basically what @Ade's reply amounts to.